# The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount. [Zeppelin, Truffle.js, Ropsten]

Tags: truffle, erc-20, gas, ropsten, openzeppelin

I am having some problem with deploying the simple Token Contract to Ropsten network.

Error is "The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount".

I tried to change Gas values many times in "Truffle.js" file, also seems like I don't have any abstract functions in "TestToken.sol" file.

Software is up to date.  But I still can't figure out what's the problem, I am just a beginner, so please help me out, would highly appreciate!

```
// truffle.js
require('dotenv').config();
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
module.exports = {
  networks: {
development: {
  host: "localhost",
  port: 9545,
  gas: 6712390,
  network_id: "*"
},
ropsten: {
    provider: function() { 
      return new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNENOMIC, "https://ropsten.infura.io/" + process.env.INFURA_API_KEY) },
    network_id: 3,
    gas: 4700000,
    },
  }
};
```

//TestToken.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Basic.sol";
import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";


contract TestToken is ERC20Basic {
    using SafeMath for uint;
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint public _totalSupply;


    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;


    function TestToken() public {
        name = "TestToken";
        symbol = "tttest";
        decimals = 18;

        _totalSupply = 4000000000000000000000000000;
        balances[0xE3FdfaAF08F4778c7E88Ed1E31696745ed610328] = _totalSupply;
        Transfer (address(0), 0xE3FdfaAF08F4778c7E88Ed1E31696745ed610328, _totalSupply); 
     }
}
```

Comment: P.S. Port number I first used 7545, just in case if there will be anyone suggesting to change

Comment: Do have a transaction ID?

Comment: @RaghavSood is this the right one? 0xd2860dcb2466e064955a46f1f40e40c5e898f87dd6f33f2a94c0874fdd2842f7

0x3af00d91a4a4b8fb935dc40a667b96e344adbe172009d8a0b90adb786ce4eeae

Comment: 2_deploy_contract.js is as follows: 
const TestToken = artifacts.require("./TestToken.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TestToken);
};

Comment: [The second one](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x3af00d91a4a4b8fb935dc40a667b96e344adbe172009d8a0b90adb786ce4eeae) seems to have deployed a contract, but it didn't emit an event, so it may not be the correct one.

Comment: @RaghavSood
I've just run the migrate command again, 0x3e2be8283ed37112c65cecf6bfb0e42ad8b835a04d2372765ef937859dc7037e

Comment: It looks like your tx is trying to deploy empty code `0x`, which implies that something in your contract source prevents it from compiling correctly

Comment: @RaghavSood what do you think prevents it? I attached my token.sol file, is there smth weird? where usually cause might hide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TestToken` inherits directly from `ERC20Basic`. `ERC20Basic` is an `interface`. That means that `TestToken` has to implement the abstract methods `ERC20Basic` declares before it can be deployed.

The error you're getting does not point towards this problem, which I think is a flaw, but it's thrown when you try to deploy a contract that does not implement all abstract methods.

A tip: instead of inheriting from OpenZeppelin's `ERC20Basic`, use `StandardToken`. It implements all functionality needed to create an ERC-20 token

Docs:

- [Abstract contracts](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#abstract-contracts)
- [Interfaces](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#interfaces)

Give this contract a try:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

import "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol";
import "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract TestToken is StandardToken {
    using SafeMath for uint;
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint public _totalSupply;


    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;


    constructor() public {

        name = "TestToken";
        symbol = "tttest";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 4000000000000000000000000000;
        balances[0xE3FdfaAF08F4778c7E88Ed1E31696745ed610328] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer (address(0), 0xE3FdfaAF08F4778c7E88Ed1E31696745ed610328, _totalSupply); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Henk, sounds like a real solution, but I tried changing it.

    import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/BasicToken.sol";
    import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
    import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

    contract TestToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

Comment: Tries to deploy a test token (0x0d0a79027660c068ab739450f9c301b720d7e60ecece055c69d09b4018f07bfb) and gives the same error "Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount."

Comment: Did you mean to use this - https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol ?

Comment: Yes, try it with `StandardToken`. `BasicToken` implements `ERC20Basic`, `StandardToken` implements both `ERC20Basic` and `ERC20`

Comment: I already changed that parts, still getting same error. But compiles properly. Above I sent you the tx code.

Comment: Have you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

This error is typically caused by either gas problems (less typical scenario) or problems in the code.

Have you tried deploying in Ganache first? If not, try that. If that succeeds, then it's most likely really a gas issue.

I used to have the same problem for an eternity but someone suggested adding a magic number for gas limit in `truffle.js`. I used to have 4000000 but I then tried this magic number and it worked. Unsure if it was just some timing issue or the magic number actually helped.

This is my Ropsten looks like (and it has worked):

```
ropsten:  {
         network_id: 3,
         host: "localhost",
         port:  8545,
         gas: 4867350,
         gasPrice: 10000000000 // 10 gwei
        },
```

Comment: Thanks mate, unfortunately number isn't magic for me :(

Comment: Yeap I will try deploying in Ganache, if I can't find any answer. My token.sol codes are shared above, can you spot any errors or weird things preventing it from deploying normally?